# TextBox I-beam pointer shifting to the right

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with a single TextBox for a user to enter a password. If an incorrect password is entered, a message box appears notifying of an error. Upon pressing the OK button, the user is returned back to the userform to try enter the correct password. Upon this second try ONLY, the I-beam pointer shifts to the right, even though the text itself remains centered. I have the following code lines immediately after that message box:

```
With TextBox1
  .Value = ""
  .SetFocus
  .SelStart = Len(.Text)
End With
```

I also have the following event procedures:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBox1.SelStart = Len(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

AND

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.SelStart = 0
End Sub
```

Regardless of anything I try, from time to time I end up with this:

[image]

NOTE, that the I-beam pointer moved from right to the left a bit by exactly 4 characters entered in the TextBox.

Any help on why this is happening and how to resolve the issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you clear the textbox?

Comment: can you add `.SelLength=0` after `.SelStart = Len(.Text)`. I don't think it will help but sometimes Microsoft does act-up.

Comment: @Moacir if I manually delete the entered text by pressing the `Backspace` button, the I-beam returns to the central position. Of course, I'd rather not  let users do that, in order to preserve fluidity.

Comment: Value of `.Text`? If `Null` then `Len(.Text) = 4`. Concat an empty string `vbNullString`to avoid `Len(.Text & vbNullString)`.

Comment: are there characters (spaces maybe) between the pointer and the`****` ? can you copy them and paste them into a text editor and examine them?

Comment: @BitAccesser I tested the TextBox using the `if IsNull(TextBox1.Value) then...` statement immediately after the "wrong password" message box, as well as in `TextBox1_Change` and `Userform1_Initialize`. NO `Null` confirmed!

Comment: @jsotola No, there are no spaces. In fact, no sooner had I entered a single character, than the I-beam moved to the right.